# Failed to read past end of stream

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, memorystream, binaryformatter

So I'm trying to send some data over the network using UDP in Unity 5.3. Because the packages might be too big to be send at once, I tried to split them into smaller ones. (note: These packages get send at 30 times per second, so loss of a certain package really doesn't matter)

What I basically did was:

1. Create byte array
2. Split into different, smaller, byte arrays
3. Add byte array to serialized class with other information
4. Convert serialized class to byte array
5. Send, and vice-versa on the receiving client

I receive the error "Failed to read past end of stream" when I try to deserialize a received byte array.

Here's the code to Deserialize:

```
private static object ToObject(byte[] data)
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return formatter.Deserialize(stream);    // exception thrown here  
    }
}
```

To Serialize:

```
private static byte[] ToByteArray(object source)
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);                
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Chunk
{
    public short ID {get; set;}
    public short ChunkAmount {get; set;}
    public System.Int64 FrameID {get; set;}
    public byte[] ChunkData {get; set;}
}
```

Any idea what could lead to this exception?

You could save me a wig by figuring this out. So thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Provided functions that handle the serialization:

```
public static List<byte[]> GetChunks(List<byte> bytes, int maxChunkSize, System.Int64 frameID)
{
    var list = new List<byte[]>(); 

    for (int i=0; i < bytes.Count; i+= maxChunkSize) 
    { 
        list.Add(bytes.GetRange(i, Mathf.Min(maxChunkSize, bytes.Count - i)).ToArray()); 
    } 

    List<byte[]> serializedChunks = new List<byte[]>();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        Chunk c = new Chunk();
        c.ID = (short)i;
        c.ChunkData = list[i].ToArray();
        c.ChunkAmount = (short)list.Count;
        c.FrameID = frameID;

        serializedChunks.Add(ToByteArray(c));
    }

    return serializedChunks;
}

//Deserialized a chunk from byte array
public static Chunk AssembleSingleChunk(byte[] serializedChunk)
{
    return (Chunk)ToObject(serializedChunk);
}

public static byte[] AssembleChunks(List<Chunk> chunks)
{
    List<Chunk> chunkList = new List<Chunk>(chunks);
    List<Chunk> sortedChunkList = chunkList.OrderBy(c => c.ID).ToList();

    List<byte> allBytes = new List<byte>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedChunkList.Count; i++)
    {
        allBytes.AddRange(sortedChunkList[i].ChunkData);
    }

    return allBytes.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: if `data` of `ToObject` were exactly the same the bytes sent, you wouldn't get this error. But it is hard to guess the bug with the code you provided...

Comment: I get that, but it keeps trowing me the exception for every received package. I update the question with the code where I assemble the serialized class

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

It didn't have anything to do with the code above, but with the buffer of the receiving client. I set the buffer to 1024 bytes, while packages being send were over that size.

So, 2 workarounds are:

1. Increase the buffer size
2. Read buffer, store data, clear buffer, read data, add data, etc.. (Not tested, just assuming)

Feel free to update us with more knowledge!